# Connecting 2 widgets, PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have a problem connecting 2 windows together without destroying the main-loop. Can you please help me connect these 2 PyQt files? The second file should open by pressing the button.

```
# usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
# from Monster import aknator

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,_encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


def Aknator():
   from Monster import aknator







class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(1695, 885)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.commandLinkButton = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Segoe UI"))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.commandLinkButton.setFont(font)
        self.commandLinkButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.commandLinkButton.setAccessibleDescription(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.commandLinkButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.commandLinkButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.commandLinkButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Aknator)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        Form.setTabOrder(self.commandLinkButton, #Future comadndlinks)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate Pro", None))
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Akantor", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the second file:

```
# usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui





try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s


try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(1096, 399)
        Form.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_5"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_8"))
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(550, 200))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_8, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_7"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_7, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_6"))
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_5, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), drops)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate Pro", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Weapon Damage", None))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Form", "Not Important HTML Code", None))

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your files are named `a.py` and `b.py`, import b in to a create a new object call `show` on it

a.py

```
# usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from b import Ui_Form2

# from Monster import aknator

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig,_encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)


def Aknator():
   from Monster import aknator



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(1695, 885)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.commandLinkButton = QtGui.QCommandLinkButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Segoe UI"))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.commandLinkButton.setFont(font)
        self.commandLinkButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.commandLinkButton.setAccessibleDescription(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.commandLinkButton.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.commandLinkButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        self.page2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_Form2()
        ui.setupUi(self.page2)

        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(self.page2.show)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.commandLinkButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Aknator)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        #Form.setTabOrder(self.commandLinkButton)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate Pro", None))
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Akantor", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

b.py

```
# usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui





try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s


try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(1096, 399)
        Form.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_5"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_8"))
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(550, 200))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_8, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_7"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.textEdit_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_7, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_6"))
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_5, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), drops)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate Pro", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Weapon Damage", None))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("Form", "Not Important HTML Code", None))
```

i had to comment out some of your code to make it run, so make sure the code you paste on Stackoverflow runs before posting your question

i'll not advice you to continue in this way you should learn to structure your project accordingly instead of modifying the auto-generated ui files from qt designer

take a look at this links to help you organize your PyQt project [Saving connect statements pyqt when UI is still changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394599/saving-connect-statements-pyqt-when-ui-is-still-changing/35394755#35394755) and

my github repo, it's PySide but the concepts are still the same

https://github.com/danidee10/Maven

Comment: Hi @PericaMatic if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.